# How to get new view from clicking barbuttonitem?

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem

I have made a barbuttonitem programmatically on a toolbar overlay. All of this appears when my camera is accessed. The button functions fine and the selector is fully capable of calling it.

Here's the overlay in .m , take a look at the doneButton selector.

```
- (UIView*)CommomOverlay  {
//Both of the 428 values stretch the overlay bottom to top for overlay function. It
doesn't cover it. 
UIView* view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,420)];
UIImageView *FrameImg = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,420)];

[FrameImg setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"newGraphicOverlay.png"]];
FrameImg.userInteractionEnabled = YES;




UIToolbar *myToolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 428, 320, 50)];


UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self
action:@selector(doneButtonPressed)];

[myToolBar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: cancelButton, flexiSpace2, flexiSpace,
doneButton, nil] animated:YES];

[view addSubview:FrameImg];
[view addSubview:myToolBar];
return view;



}
```

Here's method I'm using for my void function.

```
//NewViewController is the nib I want to bring up when done is clicked.
-(void)doneButtonPressed {

NewViewController *UIView = [[NewViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
UIView.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
[self presentModalViewController:UIView animated:NO];
[UIView release];
NSLog(@"Acknowledged!");
}
```

The button is being called, but nothing happens. As you can see I added an NSLog function to see whether it was being called or not. "Acknowledged" shows up in the log when the button is clicked, so it's not a problem with the selector. The app doesn't crash when i use the button either, which should occur had I done some heavily faulty coding (in fact I don't even get any warnings about it), as far as Xcode is considered, everything is fine which, needless to say isn't.

I also have my .h files of NewViewController in place correctly in the view controller in which this code is being implemented.

Answer (score 0):

`UIView` is the name of a class. Don't use it as the name of a variable. At best it is hugely confusing and is a probable reason for your problems. Rename `UIView` to something like `myView` everywhere in `doneButtonPressed`.

Comment: Thanks for the info, but no luck. I've done as you told, and added the NSlog again to see. It's utter confusion for me :/, the button can be clicked, the NSLog shows it's responding, but there's no action!? Please do enlighten me further more if you can.